# php openssl_pbkdf2 equivalent in java

Tags: java, php, encryption

I have some php code to encrypt a message to webservice. Now, I want to create the equivalent java code but get stuck. Please help

--PHP Code looks like

```
$length = 60;
$salt =  "MySalt";
$interation = 3000;
$bytes = openssl_pbkdf2("mypasspharse", $salt, $length, $interation, "sha1");

$value1 = substr($bytes, 0, 10);
$value2 = substr($bytes, 10, 20);
$value3 = substr($bytes, 30, 30);

return array('value1' => $value1, 'value2' => $value2, 'value3' => $value3);
```

--

I am trying to do the same thing in java using SecretKeyFactory. My java code looks like:

```
SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory
                .getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
        PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(passphrase.toCharArray(),
                salt.getBytes("UTF-8"), interation, length);
```

Now I don't know how could I get the equivalent $value1, $value2, $value3 as php code. Also, Im not sure that I am doing the correct way to write the equivalent java code with the php code above. Any idea is very appreciated.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 below examples produces the same output:

**PHP:**

```
$length = 60;
$salt =  "MySalt";
$interation = 10;
$bytes = openssl_pbkdf2("mypasspharse", $salt, $length, $interation, "sha1");

for ($i = 0; $i < 60; $i++)
{
    echo dechex(ord($bytes[$i]));
    echo '<br>';
}
```

**Java:**

```
int length = 60 * 8;
String passphrase = "mypasspharse";
String salt = "MySalt";
int iteration = 10;

SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(passphrase.toCharArray(), salt.getBytes("UTF-8"), iteration, length);

byte[] bytes = factory.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded();
for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
    System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(bytes[i] & 0xFF));
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your response. Could you please explain why length need to * 8 ?

Comment: @user3567722 length in bits